# Creating dynamically changing histogram

Tags: data-visualization, graphs, animation

I want to create a dynamically changing histogram showing 10 columns with the biggest values that changes over time: values change, new columns appear if their values in top-10 and old can disappear if their values is not in top-10.

Example where such a diagram is shown in video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=epwMa6zMfwY.

Any tools or programming languages can be used.

Comment: [Maybe your answer is already here](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/search?q=dynamic+graphs)? (Or similar searches)

Answer (score 1):

I know there are a lot of histogram classes in the DataMelt project. In particular, you want "horizontal" bar histogram. See a similar style in   https://jwork.org/dmelt/code/index.php?keyword=popularity

Search for the "histogram" on the left search field. To make the histogram dynamic, you will need to implement a loop, put sleep, and refill the container with new data after some delay.

Answer (score 0):

If you know JavaScript, then [D3js](https://d3js.org/) is the most widely used and powerful charting library out there, with lots of good documentation & code samples.

Take a look at this [histogram example](https://observablehq.com/@d3/histogram) to see how simple it can be.